# What should be done to the window was completely transparent to the keyboard and mouse?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, window, transparency

I created a tooltip.

I set all the flags (what I know) to give the tooltip focus, and so on.
Key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> closes the first my tooltip, and only then the main window after the second pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.
What should be done to the tooltip to make it 'invisible' to the keyboard and mouse?

```
tiphost=new Window();
tiphost.Owner=Window.GetWindow(this);
tiphost.AllowsTransparency=true;
tiphost.WindowStyle=WindowStyle.None;
tiphost.Width = 128;
tiphost.Height = 128;
tiphost.ShowInTaskbar=false;
tiphost.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
tiphost.Foreground=null;
tiphost.IsEnabled=false;
tiphost.Focusable=false;
tiphost.IsHitTestVisible = false;
tiphost.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
tiphost.Left=300;
tiphost.Top=300;
tiphost.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the missing flag **ShowActivated** ! (Only for keyboard focus)
If this flag is not set even with the flag **focusable = false** window has focus...

```
tiphost.ShowActivated = false;
```